# How can I listen for an element being inserted into the DOM with jQuery without using custom triggers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I want to listen for another piece of code that inserts some html into the page. I don't control that code, so I can't do `.trigger('custom_event')` and `$(document).on('custom_event')`

Additionally, the inserted div that I want to listen for is nested inside of the inserted html.

Here's what I have right now:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', "#inserted", function () {
    console.log("Inserted into document:", $(this));
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var new_node = $('<div><div id="inserted">New Div</div></div>');
    $("body").append(new_node);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AeHxQ/5/

Why doesn't the event get triggered?

Comment: `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` is a [mutation event, which are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events)

Comment: Mutation Events are deprecated, you can't expect good support for them. Your code does work in chrome 24 if you use the event `DOMNodeInserted`

Comment: Is the "blackbox code" using jQuery to insert the html? If so, include the livequery plugin and use it. The only other real option (if you must support a wide range of browsers) is to use setInterval.

Comment: @MattBall What should I use instead of DomNodeInsertedIntoDocument?

Comment: @KevinB yes the code is using jQuery

Comment: There aren't any cross-browser non-depreciated events that you can replace it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS animations with a little JavaScript, to detect when an element has been added to the DOM. The technique is explained here: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion

Comment: Seems hackish, but it works. I hate that there isn't a supported cross-browser way of doing this.

Comment: it is hackish I agree. It's one of those unpleasant situations if you have a dependency that doesn't expose methods or hooks for what you need. Hope this helped you out of a hole anyway, thanks.